# How to implement Encryption and Decryption solution in connection string on winforms application using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, encryption

I wondering how I can implement this solution on my desktop application to prevent users check config file and increase some local security.
I've created a security class with this 2 methods Not a sophisticated mechanism, but a very basic one:

```
    string Encrypt(string source, string key)
    {
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDESCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                tripleDESCryptoService.Key = byteHash;
                tripleDESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(tripleDESCryptoService.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length));
            }
        }
    }

    string Decrypt(string encrypt, string key)
    {
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDESCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                tripleDESCryptoService.Key = byteHash;
                tripleDESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypt);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tripleDESCryptoService.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length));
            }
        }
    }
```

and created a AppSettings class to get and save the connection string:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    Configuration config;

    public AppSettings()
    {
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }

    public string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
    }

    public void SaveConnectionString(string key, string value)
    {
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = value;
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ProviderName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }

}
```

Now, I want to implement this method and save the encrypted connection string and read decrypted using the entity framework, but not sure how to do this.

```
public AnnualTaxDBEntities(): base("name=AnnualTaxDBEntities")
{

}
```

I am new in c# so, Understanding is welcome.

Comment: 1 - Do not try to encrypt sensitive data if you could avoid it. If it is winforms and a corporate application (inside a domain) you should avoid database users and use a windows user authentication. 2- When cypher is really necessary, you should use better cypher algorithms and **do** **not** **use** **triple** **DES**.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new constructor that passes the connection string:

```
public AnnualTaxDBEntities(String connectionString): base(connectionString)
{

}
```

You should then simply pass the connection string into the constructor:

```
var connectionString = appSettings.GetConnectionString(key);
var dataContext = AnnualTaxDBEntities(connectionString);
```

Although note that this will not prevent any semi-competent person from seeing your connection string, it will also still be visible in the source - you should use a proper external method of secret initialization if your connection string contains sensitive data such as a credential. Or better yet, use integrated security and don't store sensitive data in the connection string in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to use External Config Files and a Protected Configuration Provider see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

This will allow you to specify your connection strings outside of the app.config file that you deploy with your app and encrypt the content of that file

Comment: This is only relevant in a hosted environment like ASP though right? Not for a user ran winforms program?

Comment: @Milney no it isn't, as the documentation I linked to details, there's literally an app.config and a web.config example there. I've used this in legacy WinForms apps

Comment: Ahh cool didn't realize you could use them with desktop apps. My other points still stand though in that this is still not secure since the information will be decrypted to be used so the user could still grab the password from RAM